# Limit assembly in its permissions in c#

Tags: c#, permissions, .net-assembly

I am developing an application in C# which is able to load dlls dynamically. These dlls are representing my "apps". I want to limit these apps in their permissions. For example (one of my main problems) prevent the access to the disc. Because my apps are using functionalities and instances of my main app domain, I don't want them to run in a seperate, sandboxed appdomain.

Is this possible anyway?

Comment: What version of .Net are you targeting.  There's a difference between .net 4 and prior versions.

Comment: Mainly targeting at .NET 4 ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned Disk access, consider using .Net's [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tk9z76%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which was designed for this purpose.

> Defines permissions and permission sets that represent the right to access various system resources.

Without replicating the documentation, let me just say that your application's code may call into the plugin's code, but restrict it from doing specific things like starting new threads or accessing a disk.

Here are some of the resources you can restrict access to:

- [System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx)
- [System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.registrypermission.aspx)
- [System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.uipermission.aspx)

Comment: Okay, i have not found any useful examples. Do you maybe have one for me?

Answer (score 2):

I'm certainly not sure how to implement it all, but it looks like the interface IPermission may be required, I located another answer here on SO that may be helpful.

[Implementing IPermission for custom code access security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840772/implementing-ipermission-for-custom-code-access-security)

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure I understand which direction you want permissions to travel. Assuming you'd like the "app" to tell the main application what it *needs* (almost like how an android app signals permissions to the phone) you could define an `IAccessRights` interface that each module implements and defines the access levels it wants or can have.

```
public interface IAccessRights
{
  Bool CanReadFromDisk { get; }
  Bool CanWriteToDisk { get; };
  Bool CanAccessNetwork { get; }
}
```

Then it's up the module to implement a class for the interface and at load time check for the object and coordinate permissions accordingly. if it needs to be two way, work out a pattern that allows the main application to set (allow) rights to the module.

Side-note: Other than that, i don't see a way to disallow direct calls like `File.Delete` without getting deep in to the system itself (hooks and what-not).